# Which is the most useful Mercurial hook for programming in a loosely connected team?

Tags: python, mercurial, hook

I recently discovered the notify extension in Mercurial which allows me quickly send out emails whenever I push changes, but I'm pretty sure I'm still missing out on a lot of functionality which could make my life a lot easier.

- notify-extension: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NotifyExtension

Which Mercurial hook or combination of interoperating hooks is the most useful for working in a loosely connected team?

Please add links to non-standard parts you use and/or add the hook (or a description how to set it up), so others can easily use it.

Answer (score 2):

I really enjoy what I did with my custom hook.  I have it post a message to my campfire account (campfire is a group based app).  It worked out really well. Because I had my clients in there and it could show him my progress.

Comment: Could you post your hook somewhere and link it here?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the hgweb stuff. You can set up RSS feeds and see all the revisions, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small set of minor hooks which might be interesting: http://fellowiki.org/hg/support/quecksilber/file/

Anyway, these are the hooks most useful to me ;-)

Comment: I found this one: http://fellowiki.org/hg/support/quecksilber/trunk/file/4dbe02b6965f/quecksilber/trac_integration.py

Did I miss any?